# Consequences of $G$ having exactly $3$ irreducible characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, solvable-groups

Suppose a finite group $G$ has exactly irreducible characters $\chi_1 = \mathbb{I}, \chi_2,\chi_3$.

i) Show that G is soluble and deduce it has a non-trivial one-dimensional character $\chi_2$.

ii) Show that $\dim \chi_3 \in \{1,2\}$.

I cannot get anywhere with either part so hints only please.

Comment: How much background do you have in character theory (the first one could for example be deduced just from knowing that the group had at most 3 distinct degrees of irreducible characters, but that is probably overkill).

Comment: I know character theory (supposedly)

Comment: What do you mean by "the" result?

Comment: Bad english, it means I should be comfortable with character theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you find all finite groups with exactly $3$ conjugacy classes? Hint: there are only two of them.

Comment: See also the answer I gave to the other question you recently edited, sandstone.

Comment: I still cant get it from this

Comment: You know that the number of irreducible characters is the same as the number of conjugacy classes, right? So once you find all groups with $3$ conjugacy classes. you can prove your statements for each one.